# Catalyst FormFu DBIC error - using dot notation in a resultset

Tags: perl, catalyst, dbix-class, html-formfu

I've inherited a Perl Catalyst application that I'm trying to port to a new server.  The application uses FormFu with the HTML::FormFu::Model::DBIC module used to load data from a result set.

I have a DBIx table, say `MyTable`, with an auto-generated Result implementation and a custom ResultSet implementation.  In the custom  ResultSet implementation there are some subroutines, e.g. `sub my_sub`, that return filtered subsets of data.

In a FormFu YAML file, the following will fetch all the records from MyTable:

```yaml
elements:
  - type: Select
    model_config:
      resultset: MyTable
```

This is equivalent to fetching, in a Controller, `$schema->resultset('MyTable')`.  This executes correctly on both the old server and the new server.

On the old server, I can use dot notation to call the subroutine to fetch the subset of records it returns like so:

```yaml
elements:
  - type: Select
    model_config:
      resultset: MyTable.my_sub
```

This is equivalent to fetching in a Controller, `$schema->resultset('MyTable')->my_sub`.  This executes correctly on the old server.  On the new server, in FormFu, this throws the error:

*Can't find source for MyTable.my_sub at /[...]/HTML/FormFu/Model/DBIC.pm*

I've added debugging to the FormFu DBIC.pm module to see if it's doing anything special.  The code it calls is `$schema->resultset($rs_name);` where `rs_name` is the name given in the `resultset` parameter, "MyTable.my_sub", and `$schema` is of type `Moose::Meta::Class::__ANON__::SERIAL`, which I assume is some kind of wrapper.  Within a Catalyst controller, a schema is of type `myapp::Schema`.

What am I missing?  Is there some configuration option I need to set?  Some module I need to install?  I can't find any documentation or examples that show a FormFu resultset with dot notation, yet on the old server it works.

Comment: Sounds like there might be a version mismach, maybe of FormFu. You can check which versions you have most easily by running `perl -MHTML::FormFu::Model::DBIC\ 9` in the terminal on both servers. You might want to compare a few different things in the dependency chain. Do you install dependencies with a cpanfile or Makefile and a CPAN client, or do you use system packages?

Comment: I used `cpan -l` to list the modules on the old server and then `cpan install` to install them on the new server (sudo in both cases).  The versions of Catalyst, DBIx, and FormFu are all the same. 2.0.3 in FormFu's case.

Answer (score 2):

When I attempted to add logging to the working DBIC.pm file, I discovered that the developer from whom I inherited this application symlinked the module's DBIC.pm file to a custom DBIC.pm file in his own home folder with the extended functionality.

Comment: Add this to the very short list of things no one on StackOverflow ever would have guessed! That's a really wicked landmine to leave for the future maintainers.

Comment: That's really annoying. Glad you figured it out. I voted to close your question as off-topic, because it won't be helpful to anyone else.

Comment: Yep, super annoying.